# Assisted-autoplugging (cutting) of uridecodebin

Tags: gstreamer

```
bool demuxDone = false;

gboolean
autopluggerCallback (GstElement * elem, GstPad *pad, GstCaps * caps)
{
    if (cmpType(caps, "video/x-h264")) {
        relayVideoPad = pad;
        demuxDone = true;
    }
    if (cmpType(caps, "audio/x-ac3")) {
        relayAudioPad = pad;
        demuxDone = true;
    }

    if (demuxDone) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I connected the `autoplug-continue` signal handler to `uridecodebin`. My goal is to prevent it from creating anything after the `tsdemux` and then connect video/audio to `flvmux`.

But the problem I am having is that one more element is still created, the `multiqueue` that is connected right after the `tsdemux0`. Why? I tried to detect the creation of a demuxer by catching the `element-added` signal instead of waiting for `video/x-h264`, but the result is the same.

The resulting pipeline is dumped to dot:
        http://pastebin.com/acBUdfpi

Well, I can probably just connect `multiqueue` to the `flvmux`, but then I do not know how to get the multiqueue pointer. I tried `gst_pad_get_peer`->`gst_get_pad_parent_element`, (to go from demuxer src-video-pad to the next element), but `gst_get_pad_parent_element` returns 0 even though the peer is non 0.